# Mapping an Enum with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I'm trying to map a string stored in the database (ex. ABC1, BCD2) to an enum (ABC_1, BCD_2).

With hibernate I was able to do this with the following hibernate mapping

```
<typedef name="LinkEnum" class="GenericEnumUserType">
    <param name="enumClass">types.LinkEnum</param>
    <param name="identifierMethod">value</param>
    <param name="valueOfMethod">fromValue</param>
</typedef>
```

and in the LinkEnum

```
@XmlType(name = "LinkEnum")
@XmlEnum
public enum LinkEnum {

@XmlEnumValue("ABC1")
ABC_1("ABC1"),
@XmlEnumValue("BCD2")
BCD_2("BCD2");
private final String value;

LinkEnum(String v) {
    value = v;
}

public String value() {
    return value;
}

public static LinkEnum fromValue(String v) {
    for (LinkeEnum c: LinkEnum.values()) {
        if (c.value.equals(v)) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
}
}
```

In the JPA class, I'm trying to do the same kind of mapping, however it's having a problem mapping the enum still. Is there an equivalent way to do this with JPA?

```
private LinkEnum link;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "LINK", nullable = false, length = 8)
public LinkEnum getLink() {
    return this.link;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the entire class definition ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a javax.persistence.AttributeConverter (gives your more freedom than the above solution).

For this, implement a class that implements AttributeConverter and annotate your member in the class as follows:

@Convert(converter = NameOfYourConverter.class)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good explanation on the documentation of @Enumerated

```
public enum EmployeeStatus {FULL_TIME, PART_TIME, CONTRACT}

public enum SalaryRate {JUNIOR, SENIOR, MANAGER, EXECUTIVE}

@Entity public class Employee {
   //@Enumerated is not mandatory. If it's not specified, It assumes to be an ORDINAL (by default)
   public EmployeeStatus getStatus() {...}
   ...
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   public SalaryRate getPayScale() {...}
   ...
```

}

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html

Answer (score 0):

Define your Enum like this :

`public enum LinkEnum {ABC_1("ABC1"), BCD_2("BCD2")}`

And your entity, you can annotated like this :

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   public LinkEnum getLinkEnum() {...}
```

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?